# check python object is none is not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup and following code block to check this html tr object has th in it.

```
if tr.find('th') is not None:
           result[tr.find('th').text] = tr.find('td').text
```

But it is always entering in if block and returning an attribute error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What if `tr.find('td')` is `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **two distinct** `tr.find()` calls, one for `'th'`, the other for `'td'`. The latter can return `None` too, but you don't test for that so the `tr.find('td').text` can raise an `AttributeError` exception.

You need to test both results. Perhaps store an empty string or other default if the `td` cell is missing?

```
header, cell = tr.find('th'), tr.find('td')
if header is not None:
    result[header.text] = cell.text if cell is not None else ''
```